# How to run and publish .NETCore Xunit tests on VSTS (Vs2017)?

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines

I had two build steps in VSTS:

1. To run tests (VSTS cmd task):  DOTNET test -xml TEST-results.xml
2. To publish test results step (VSTS test publish task): format=XUnit and the file name from previous step

But after I upgraded to VS2017 the -XML tag is not working anymore. I changed step one to use this:
test --logger "trx;LogFileName=TEST-results.xml"

but the second step throws an error "*Invalid results file. Please make sure the Test Result Format field in the task matches the result format of the file*"

Is there another way to run .NetCore tests on VSTS? or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change "Test Result Format" to "VSTest of Publish Test" result step/task, it reads the result file correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was it.

Answer (score 8):

starain-MSFT's answer will work, unless you want/need the xunit tests to be logged using an xunit logger.  In that case, you'll need to do two things.

1. Add https://www.nuget.org/packages/XunitXml.TestLogger/1.0.2-pre-rtm as package ref to your *test* project, either through 'Manage NuGet Packages' in VS, or by adding the ref in your csproj file manually, i.e.

`<PackageReference Include="xunitxml.testlogger" Version="1.0.2-pre-rtm" />`

2. Modify the VSTS dotnet test build step to use this logger:
   `dotnet test -a:. -l:xunit`
   The `-a:.` switch, which specifies the adapter path, is only necessary for CLI tools V15.0, in 15.1 that can be removed (as discussed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/522#issuecomment-287797917)).  As of today, the VS2017 Hosted Queue is using 15.0, so you'll need the `-a:.` on VSTS for now.
   The `-l:xunit` uses the friendlyname, which I think isn't so friendly since you have to dig into the source code for the particular logger to find the attribute where it is specified (as seen [here](https://github.com/spekt/xunit.testlogger/blob/49642e2022c0413eb22a86d16dbebd31b9d836d6/src/Xunit.Xml.TestLogger/XunitXmlTestLogger.cs#L31) for xunit and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/blob/fd0fe3df347a081b56c4da89f85a3e1ff463a4e7/src/Microsoft.TestPlatform.Extensions.TrxLogger/Utility/Constants.cs#L20) for trx)

The docs for the `-l` switch are spotty to say the least, but in the github for vstest, there is a [document](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/report.md) which talks about test loggers and links to their repositories and nuget packages, which after you look at the source for the friendlyname, gets you all the way there for whichever logger you need.  If you need a custom logger, those are great examples to help understand how to implement.

Finally, the publish step that you used originally should be fine, since the output file is still called TestResults.xml

Comment: You saved hell lot of time for me. Thanks mate!

Comment: Both of the links to source code on github are broken since they are not canonical URLs. A canonical URL takes into account the version of the code, e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/blob/4d89670131ea04d0d8841c2f4c5ea4045f62fe7c/src/Microsoft.TestPlatform.Extensions.TrxLogger/TrxLogger.cs#L29

BTW - you can switch to the canonical URL when viewing GitHub source code with the 'Y' keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Links are fixed - canonical pro tip assimilated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dotnet xunit` instead of `dotnet test`. See [Getting Started with .NET Core](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core).

Comment: Thanks!  That's a great solution.  However, that CLI command is currently in Beta.  If your rules require that you use RTM or as close as possible, the other solutions are going to be your best bet for the moment.  Also, worth noting that the 'dotnet xunit -xml flag uses the project root, so if you need test results going into TestResults/ you'll need to specify that as part of the file path.

Comment: FTR, `dotnet xunit` no longer exists: https://xunit.github.io/releases/2.4